# Python, GTK, WebKit - Multiple instances of webview

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

So I've recently begun learning Python, using python, gtk, and webkit to build a browser.

I'm just having trouble with one thing.  For the most part I can figure these kinds of things out, but really having trouble with this one.

I've got a button that adds a new tab.  It gives it it's own 'position' to identify itself for later on when I populate the websites title in the tab label.  Currently, the label defaults to the tab number.  I've got the following code to create the tab and a new instance of Gtk.ScrolledWindow inside of the tabs page, and then I try to add a WebKit WebView inside of the corresponding scrolled window, but it shoots out an error message.

Code:

```
def on_addtab_clicked(self, widget):
    self.num = self.num + 1
    self.newtablabel = Gtk.Label(self.num)
    self.newpagelabel = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.notebook.insert_page(self.newpagelabel, self.newtablabel, self.num)
    self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
    print self.notebook.get_current_page()
    print self.num
    self.get_pages()
    self.notebook.show_all()
    self.show_all()
```

Error:

Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type WebKitWebView to a container of type GtkScrolledWindow, but the widget is already inside a container of type GtkScrolledWindow, please use gtk_widget_reparent()

Do I need to create an entirely new instance of WebKit here?  I'm definitely missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Pastebin if you'd like to see the entire code: http://pastebin.com/vXcLd1tT

Video of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhtJDrWr8t8&feature=youtu.be

UPDATE:

So I've updated the code to add a new webkit.webview to each new tab that is opened, and it works. You get a right click menu on every page, however, the address bar now won't function.  Is there a way to get the ID of the currently open webview (active one) and push the url request directly to that one?  Then when you switch to a new tab, the url will go to the correct page:

```
def on_addtab_clicked(self, widget):
    self.num = self.num + 1
    self.newtablabel = Gtk.Label(self.num)
    self.newpagelabel = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
self.newpagelabel.add(WebKit.WebView())
WebKit.WebView().show()
    self.notebook.insert_page(self.newpagelabel, self.newtablabel, self.num)
    print self.notebook.get_current_page()
    print self.num
    self.get_pages()
    self.notebook.show_all()
    self.show_all()

def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
    url = widget.get_text()
    if ' ' in url:
        url = 'https://www.google.ca/search?q=' + url
        self.urlentry.set_text(url)
    elif '.' not in url:
        url = 'https://www.google.ca/search?q=' + url
        self.urlentry.set_text(url)
    elif not url.startswith('http'):
        url = 'http://' + url
        self.urlentry.set_text(url)

    WebKit.WebView().open(url)
```

Comment: You can't have a single widget (webview) inside many containers (ScrolledWindows) at the same time. You can't add it multiple times to the same container either (this seems to be what you are doing)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So,  After tinkering around, I've got webview showing in each new tab (you can tell, when you right click, you get a menu), however this breaks the functionality of the address bar.  Is there a way to get the current webview which is showing, and redirect the url request into that webview?